# Parsing XML in Haskell

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

I am trying to learn me some Haskell and I wanted to parse some XML files with the following structure:

```
<properties>
  <property name="a">
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property name="b">
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
</properties>
```

Following the example from the [wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HXT/Practical/Simple1) I can search for all properties by

```
runX (readDocument [ withValidate no] "my.xml" 
           >>> deep (isElem >>> hasName "properties")
```

but how can I extract only the value element of `property name="b"`?

Comment: If you are starting to learn Haskell, then I would recommend you to start from something more simpler. I haven't worked with HXT library but I think it is based upon the Arrow combinator which is an slightly advanced concept. I have found tagsoup library to be much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TagSoup indeed did the thing for me. Based on the [tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup-0.12/src/tagsoup.htm) I found

```
module Main where
import Text.HTML.TagSoup

searchXML :: IO ()
searchXML = do
      rsp <- readFile "test.xml"
      let tags  = parseTags rsp
      let links = extr "value" [] $
                  extr "property" [("name","b")] tags
      let value = fromTagText $ links !! 0
      putStr value
      where 
          extr a b c = drop 1 $ takeWhile (~/= TagClose a) $
                       dropWhile (~/= TagOpen a b) c

main = searchXML
```

which prints just the value `2`. But I am pretty sure the code can be simplified a lot.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I find that `HXT` is a quite complex library to use.
My understanding so far is that you transform a document in another one using arrows chain.

If you want to learn arrows, you may find that my solution is cheating, but for me it did the job :
I just use `XPath` (`cabal install hxt-xpath`) and produce an output document.

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Text.XML.HXT.XPath.Arrows 

main :: IO ()
main = do
      runX $ readDocument [] "my.xml"
            >>>
            root [] [ selem "values" [getXPathTrees "/properties/property[@name=\"b\"]/value"]]
            >>>
            writeDocument [withIndent yes] "out.xml"
      return ()
```

yielding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<values>
  <value>2</value>
</values>
```